# Meteor List Sorting and Dragging Using Rubaxa Sorting Script

Tags: javascript, meteor, rubaxa-sortable

I'm new to Meteor and Javascript.

I'm trying to implement the sort library found here:

https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/tree/master/meteor

I know this is probably simple, but the simpliest invocation of the code here: 
{{sortable }}

still leaves me a bit baffled. I've tried passing collections like:

`{{sortable PlayersList}}` but, have no idea what the output is supposed to be. I learn by example, can someone help me out by giving me the quickest implementation of the library?

This is my first time posting on a forum in a long time. I usually can Google-Fu my way around.

Here is my html file:

`
  sortof

## Welcome to Meteor!

{{> hello}}

Unsorted:
  {{#each showplayers}}

```
<li>{{name}}: {{score}}</li>
```

{{/each}}

Sorted:

{{#sortable items=PlayersList}}

```
{{#each name}}

hi
<li>{{name}}: {{score}}</li>

{{/each}}
```

{{/sortable}}

`

and here is my web output:

`
Welcome to Meteor!

Unsorted:
Bob: 0
Larry: 0
Henry: 0
Sorted:

`

Thanks!

Comment: The output should be a list of players that are sortable when you drag them. Not sure that really helps though. Can print out a player list without sortable?

Comment: I guess that's my question. Should the list output automatically or should I add something to get the data out of the list. Here's a sample of my data: `PlayersList.insert({
    name: "Bob",
    score: 0
});`

Comment: You need multiple items to be able to sort

Comment: I think I am. I updated the original post to reflect my code.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  {{#sortable items=players}}
</template>

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
    players: function () {
        return Players.find();
    }
});
```

And for more complex examples, see:

**HTML:** https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/blob/master/meteor/example/client/define-object-type.html

**JS:** https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/blob/master/meteor/example/client/define-object-type.js

Comment: I'm sure I'm doing something absolutely ridicoulous. I've created a meteorpad here so you can see what I'm doing. Thank you very much for your time. http://meteorpad.com/pad/bTef4LYPLLNFS7Jdd/Xamtest

Comment: Your example works. Drag the items in the table and they'll get rearranged.

Comment: Actually, the dragging works, but not as expected. For some reason you can even drag items that aren't supposed to be draggable.

Comment: Heh. Well that's an awesome step in the right direction! Thank you very much. I've been banging my head on getting this library to work for a few days. I'll try to pass it forward!

Comment: I posted an issue on GitHub about it sorting the unsorted list (and items not appearing in the sorted list): https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/issues/341 (issues can also be a good place to look if you're having problems)